# Submit multiple fasta sequence using WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl

I want to summit multiple protein sequences in fasta format on [this server](http://harrier.nagahama-i-bio.ac.jp/sosui/sosuiG/sosuigsubmit.html) using following perl script

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

# get the webpage with the form

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->show_progress(1);

my $url = "http://harrier.nagahama-i-bio.ac.jp/sosui/sosu/sosuigsubmit.html";
$mech->get($url);

# just checks to see if scripts call properly

sub validateInput{
    my $file = shift;
    my $inFh = IO::File->new( $file ) || die "can't open input file\n";
    close($inFh);
    return 1;
}

validateInput($ARGV[0]);

# fill the fields with the appropriate data and submit

my $fields = {
    'in'    => $ARGV[0],
    'value' => 'Exec'
};

$mech->submit_form(
     fields => $fields,
);

# print results

print $mech->content();
```

But every time I getting the result like this

```
<HTML>
<bR><bR><bR>
<TABLE>
<TR><TD ALIGN=left WIDTH=300>TOTAL PROTEINS</TD><TH>0</TH></TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN=left WIDTH=300>TOTAL MEMBRANE PROTEINS</TD><TH>0</TH></TR>
<TR><TD ALIGN=left WIDTH=300>PERCENTAGE</TD><TH> 0.0 %</TH></TR>
</TABLE>
</HTML>
```

Which is a result page when you submit form without input. So I suspect that there is some problem with my sequence submission. My input file look like this

```
>ATCG00420
MQGTLSVWLAKRGLVHRSLGFDYQGIETLQIKPEDWHSIAVILYVYGYNYLRSQCAYDVAPGGLLASVYHLTRIEYGV    NQAEEVCIKVFTHRSNPRIPSVFWVWKSTDFQERESYDMLGITYDSHPRLKRILMPESWIGWPLRKDYIAPNFYEIQDAY
>ATCG00360
MSAQSEGNYAEALQNYYEAMRLEIDPYDRSYILYNIGLIHTSNGEHTKALEYYFRALERNPFLPQAFNNMAVICHYRGEQAIQQGDSEMAEAWFAQAAEYWKQAITLTPGNYIEAQNWLTITRRFE
```

and I am calling my script like this

```
perl my_script input.seq >output
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Is that space in `sosuiG   /sosuigsubmit` in the original code?

Comment: If that is your real code then the URL is wrong. Spaces are not allowed in URLs. You should examine `$mech->success` to make sure your calls to `get` and `submit_form` succeeded, `$mech->status` to find out what was wrong if it failed, and `$mech->text` to see what the form actually looks like.

Comment: Also, it's very wasteful to open a file to check that it's valid. You can use `-e` to make sure it exists, `-f` to make sure it's a file and not a directory, `-s` to make sure it's not empty, and `-r` to make sure it can be read, all without going through the lengthy process of opening it.

Comment: @borodin, thanks for your comments. I am a beginner. Actualy there is no space in url.

Comment: Always start your Perl files with `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, this line:

```
    'in'    => $ARGV[0],
```

Means that you're sending them a filename, rather than the contents of the file.  You'll need to get the contents first, and send those.  Libraries like [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) are handy for this.

Comment: Note that [File::Slurp has a nasty bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=83126) (still unfixed). [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) seems to be better.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me towards the right direction. I finally solved it. :)

Comment: @pali no problem, feel free to accept my answer if it was the key to your problem.

Comment: @melpomene thanks, I updated my answer to reflect that.